# Project Online Intercept Ribbon Save Button Action

Tags: jquery, project-online, html5

Need to intercept Project Online Save Button. To perform some action before Project Server update starts. Once my action is successful, I would like original code of Project Server Save to take over.

Below is the Original HTML available

```
<a class="ms-cui-ctl-large " id="Ribbon.Tabs.PDP.Home.Project.Save-Large" onclick="return false;" href="javascript:;" mscui:controltype="Button" aria-describedby="Ribbon.Tabs.PDP.Home.Project.Save_ToolTip" role="button" unselectable="on"><span class="ms-cui-ctl-largeIconContainer" unselectable="on"><span class=" ms-cui-img-32by32 ms-cui-img-cont-float ms-cui-imageDisabled" unselectable="on"><img class="" style="top: -32px;left: -320px;" unselectable="on" src="/_layouts/15/1033/images/ps32x32.png?rev=45" data-themekey="#"></span></span><span class="ms-cui-ctl-largelabel" unselectable="on">Save</span></a>
```

Also, I have tried addEventListener as below

> document.body.addEventListener('click', function( event ) {
>   if(event.target.id=="Ribbon.Tabs.PDP.Home.Project.Save-Large"){
>   console.log('mouse button click: ', event.target.id);
>   SaveData(_defaultVal,projectName,_curTAB); } }, false);

But unfortunately, I was unable to intercept the save click. However, If i try mouseover it is working fine.

Any idea ?